# Augmented Dickey-Fuller test says its stationary, but it doesn't look like so (IMHO)

Tags: time-series, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

This is my TS:
[image: Original TS Plot]

As I apply the `adf.test(myts)`, see below the result:

```r
    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  TQ_volume_ts
Dickey-Fuller = -4.5041, Lag order = 3, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary

Warning message:
In adf.test(TQ_volume_ts) : p-value smaller than printed p-value
```

As per the p-value, the TS is supposed to be stationary, but from the plot, I see that the mean is not constant over time, there seem to be a trend, it doesn't fluctuate around 0 (which I think it's not necessarily a must to be stationary, please let know if I am wrong about this as well) and the standard deviation is not constant over time either.

What am I missing? Is that really stationary or I can't rely exclusively on ADF to find out whether my TS is stationary or not.

Comment: It's not that you can't rely on the ADF test, it's more the fact that given your relatively small sample, there's not enough evidence to reject the null hypothesis (i.e., stationarity).

Comment: So wasn't it supposed to be the other way around? ADF test should retrieve a higher p-value?

Comment: No, the p-value is what it is. Use your knowledge about the series to think about whether it would be stationary or not in practice.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Comment: The output from `tseries::adf.test` is somewhat confusing, because it uses the version of the ADF test with a deterministic time trend, so that your observed process is not actually stationary under either the null or the alternative (the "alternative hypothesis: stationary" bit is referring to the autoregressive coefficient of the residual after removing the deterministic part, not the observed process). This indeed looks more like a deterministic time trend than a unit root, judging from the chart.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rely on ADF to identify whether this time series is stationary for two reasons.

1. This time series looks like it *could* have a seasonal trend, but ADF only tests for presence of a unit root. ADF will not help you if there's a seasonal trend.
2. This looks like a sample size of 30 or so, i.e. well within the range where most of the information you have on this time series is going to come from your priors.

You should really just ask yourself, do you expect your time series to be stationary or not? What is this a time series of? For instance, if these are quarterly earnings, I would not expect them to be stationary before taking first differences. But if it's GDP growth rates, I'd look at that and go "Looks ok."

Comment: Thanks alot. As far as the data and my thoughts about it, it's a postgraduation project. The data is real (it's the empty space volume of tanks in a Storage Tank Farm). I've been trying to explain the practical through the theory. I don't much feedback from the data owner, they are not so quick on answering my questions.